# Tqdm status bar shown before executed

Tags: python, tqdm

I have a tqdm progress bar:

```
print('foo')
for status in tqdm(cursor.items(count)):
    #process status
    pass
```

I print some messages before the loop but the progress bar is shown before them. Is there any kind of multi threading or how can i fix this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

tqdm works in a thread (that's good as the application won't stuck because of the progress bar) and therefore the progress bar is shown before the prints.

As the machine sees that print is an IO action so the machine gives priority to the tqdm.

You need to sleep just before and after the loop. To do so, use `time.sleep(x)`(x is in seconds) before and after the loop to stop the problem. Remember to `import time` at the start of your code. Experiment with different values of x, but just 0.1 will probably work fine.

Comment: you can also try with the `flush` keyword argument of print to force the display like `print("foo",flush=True)`

Comment: It does not seem to work on windows, but it's more elegant than waiting

Comment: This is not the reason why the printouts end up in the wrong order, and sleeping for a fixed amount of time may still fail in certain situations depending on how quickly Python can process the various commands that print to the terminal (even though in this [MWE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example) sleeping will probably work). See my answer for a solution in which you don't have to use `time.sleep`.

Comment: This solution did not work for me while adding `flush=True` to my print statement did (I'm on windows)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `print` by default prints to `sys.stdout` while [`tqdm` by default prints to `sys.stderr`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tqdm#parameters), which makes them desynchronized.

You can either specify `file=sys.stdout` to `tqdm` or specify `file=sys.sterr` to `print` to make both print to the same stream, or you can call `sys.stdout.flush` before and `sys.stderr.flush` after each call to `tqdm`.

Answer (score 1):

I can report how a couple of the solutions reported worked for me on Windows 10.  I too was having the problem of tqdm's bar output being interrupted by the print executed prior to tqdm.
The solution that worked for me is

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```

The one that did not was the addition to the print of

```
flush=True
```

I think the sys.stdout.flush is the best so far as it's EXACTLY what needs to be done... the output on stdout needs to be flushed so that it's completed prior to the first output on stderr by tqdm... the most basic of I/O problems.

I LOVE this little widget's ability to bring a bit of elegance to the otherwise boring world of stdio.